# Why does a dropped database in Snowflake still show up in the web UI?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using the free trial of Snowflake to experiment with it.  I created a new database (TEST_DB), created a schema (TEST_SCHEMA) and some tables.  I then dropped the database (TEST_DB) which seemed to work.  However, from the Snowsight web UI, the TEST_DB database still shows up there.  I tried refreshing and also navigating to completely different pages and then returning.  Why does the database I dropped still show up?  From the attached image, you can see I issued a "use test_db;" and received a message saying the "object does not exist" so it is obviously gone.

[image]

Comment: Did you refresh the page?

Comment: @MikeWalton - I did yes.

Comment: Must be some sort of bug because I renamed my worksheet and now it is gone.

Comment: Its some sort of bug or refresh problem with Chrome because if I close my tab and log back in then the database is gone.  I reproduced the problem in Chrome, but the same thing doesn't happen in MS Edge.